# don't get a sorted and clean result from get() function laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The code below doesn't give me the correct result from the query.

```php
$studentMeta = StudentMeta::where([
    'meta_key' => 'brother_phone',
    'students_id' => 9
])->get();
print_r($studentMeta);
```

I get this result:
[image]

However, I expect something like this:

```
$studentMeta => Array
(
    [id] => 49
    [meta_key] => brother_phone
    [meta_value] => 7926161024
    [created] => 2019-04-17 00:10:03
    [students_id] => 9
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you try using toArray() rather than get() ??  See if it works?

Comment: You're viewing a `Collection` of `StudentMeta` models; this is the expected output. If you need it in another format (which honestly is done automatically on iteration, or when passing to view/api response), you'll need to convert it yourself. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's it because you are getting a collection of Model instances (because you are using `get()` instead of `first()` for example).

If you want to return it to the view, Laravel will call the `->toArray()` method under the hood.

Try doind this to see your expected result:

```
$studentMeta =  StudentMeta
                    ::where(['meta_key' => 'brother_phone', 'students_id'=> 9])
                    ->get();

dd($studentMeta->toArray());
```

Check this section of the documentation: [Eloquent Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization)

Comment: toArray() worked but I used get() in multiple other queries but didn't get such an answer.
this is working fine:
$f = faculty::where('active',1)->get();

Comment: `.first()` will also return model instance.