# don't get a sorted and clean result from Laravel Eloquent queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, configuration

I have this code which to find the student data from the database:

```
   public function edit($id)
    {
        $student = Students::find($id);
        // $facs = faculty::get();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($student );
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
        return view('pages.forms.editstudent')->with(['studentdata'=>$student,'stid'=>$id]); //,'f'=>$facs
    }
```

And this is the result I get from the query:
[image]

but this is what I expect to get as a result:

```
 Array(
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Whitney
        [last] => Walker
        [father_name] => Ahmad
        [gf_name] => mahmood
        [ssid] => 45612
        [birthdate] => 2010-04-25
        [blood_group] => dsfasdf
        [schools_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 2019-04-16 19:33:34
        [updated_at] => 2019-04-16 19:33:34
    )
```

and I had the same issue before here: 
[don't get a sorted and clean result from get() function laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716236/dont-get-a-sorted-and-clean-result-from-get-function-laravel-eloquent)

but in previews projects it was working okay so I'm asking is there any configuration for this in Laravel or something like that change to change all the query responses.

Comment: If you need it as an array, `Students::find($id)->toArray()` perhaps? But you can just access the properties in the blade and keep the object (so `{{$studentdata->name}}` in the blade).

Comment: I tried this and it's working but as I mention I didn't need to use toArray() before so  why now it responds like this(include extra data) any configuration missed or ..?

Comment: I don't know what you did before, so hard for me to say why you need it now. If you need it as an array now, just call `->toArray()`. ;-) It all depends on how you intend to use it in the blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent will always return an object or a collection of objects unless you specify that you want the result as an array with `->toArray()`.

If you want the result from a query as an array per default you should use repository pattern rather than configure Eloquent, because you should learn use the framework as is intended.